# Decrypt XML file using local X.509 Certificate .PFX in VB.NET

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, encryption, saml

I am trying to decrypt (AES algorithm, not RSA) a XML file using a X.509 Certificate and the Private Key, but I am getting an Exception saying

> Unable to retrieve the decryption key

This is part of the code:

```
Dim privateCert As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath("~/privateCertificate.pfx"), "pwd", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet)
```

I already installed the `.pfx` in the MMC, but it still does not work.
This is the method:

```
Private Function DecryptXML(ByRef xmlFile As XmlDocument, privateCert As X509Certificate2, logger As Logger) As XmlDocument

    Dim decryptedDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

    'Check the arguments
    If (xmlFile Is Nothing) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("Doc")
    End If

    'Create a new EncryptedXML object
    Dim exml As EncryptedXml = New EncryptedXml(xmlFile)

    Try
        'Decrypt the XML Message
        exml.DecryptDocument()
        'Parse from EncryptedXml to XmlDocument
        decryptedDoc.LoadXml(exml.ToString())
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Error Decrypting
        logger.LogException(LogLevel.Error, ex.Message, ex)
    End Try

    Return decryptedDoc
End Function
```

Comment: I don't see how you're using the privateCert to encrypt or decrypt - are you sure this is the latest version of your code?